# Create an array from an array

Tags: php, functions, array

I've got an array of images attached to a post, and can output them sequentually just fine:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

How can I get three images at a time from the array, then step one image forward to create the following arrays of three images:

1 2 3

2 3 4

3 4 5

4 5 6

and so on?

Here's my code:

```
global $rental;

$images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $rental_id,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
) );

if ($images) :

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($images as $attachment_id => $image) :

        $i++;

        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );

        ?>

        <div class="item <?php if($i == 1){echo ' active';} ?> class="<?php echo $i; ?>"">
            <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: Might be easier to help if we know what you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to have multiple loops and output 3 images at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your array using the following

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$number_of_elements = 3;

$count = count( $array );
$split = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i <= $count - 1; $i++ ) {
    $slices = array_slice( $array, $i , $number_of_elements);
    if ( count( $slices ) != $number_of_elements )
        break;

    $split[] = $slices;
}

print_r( $split );
```

Comment: I'm just trying to integrate my images into it though, and at the moment it's not working quite right. I'm a little stuck as to how to get it to pull the images.

I've got `$array = $images;` set up now, and `print_r( $slices );` outputs all of the meta related to each of the attachments. I just need to be able to get the URL of the image- any ideas on how I would achieve this?

Comment: I've updated the code, this should make it easier. You now have an array `$split` containing all the slices

Comment: Thanks- I've replaced `print_r( $split )` with:

`    if ($split) :

  foreach ($split as $outeritem) :
   
   echo 'Outer Top <br/>';
   
    foreach ($split as $inneritem) :

     echo 'Inner Top <br/>';
      
     echo 'Image Url: ' . $inneritem . '<br/>';
     
     echo 'Inner Bottom <br/>';

     endforeach;
   
   echo 'Outer Bottom <hr/>';

  endforeach;
  
 endif;`

Which works fine and seems to output the structure as I want it. The last piece of the puzzle is getting `$inneritem` to output the URL of the image, rather than just the word `array`- any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for a more elegant solution.

Example:

```
$array = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );

$chunks = array_chunk( $array, 3 );
```

The value of `$chunks` in the example above would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

Short and sweet without the need for any loops.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help- the chunks i'm after are 1 2 3, 2 3 4, 3 4 5 and so on.